# how to filter a combo box that is created by a Ng-Repeat based on the same combo box in the previous row in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, combobox, angularjs-filter, dynamic-forms

I have a select element that is repeated by a ng-repeat directive when the "*Addbutton*" clicked . the object that fills the select element has a format like this :

```
{ id: 1, Title: 'AAA', priority: 1 },
```

I want when user selects an option from this combo box and clicks on the "*Addbutton*",
in the next row only options that have **priority** greater than **the previous selected item priority** would be list and shown .

This is my code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApplication">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var MainApplication = angular.module('mainApplication', []);
        MainApplication.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope)
        {
            $scope.AddressPrefix = [
                                { id: 1, Title: 'AAA', priority: 1 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'BBB', priority: 2 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'CCC', priority: 3 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'DDD', priority: 4 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'EEE', priority: 5 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'FFF', priority: 6 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'GGG', priority: 7 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'HHH', priority: 8 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'III', priority: 2 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'jjj', priority: 2 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'kkk', priority: 2 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'LLL', priority: 10 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'MMM', priority: 9 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'ooo', priority: 7 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'PPP', priority: 12 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'qqq', priority: 3 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'RRR', priority: 13 },
                                { id: 1, Title: 'zzz', priority: 14 },

                                    ];

            $scope.AddressControls = [{ id: 1 }];
            $scope.btnAddressAdd_click = function () {
                var newItemNo = $scope.AddressControls.length + 1
                $scope.AddressControls.push({ 'id': newItemNo });
            };
            $scope.btnAddressRemove_click = function () {
                var lastItem = $scope.AddressControls.length - 1
                $scope.AddressControls.splice(lastItem);
            };
        }]);
    </script>

</head>
<body dir="rtl" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="row" >

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button type="button" id="btnAddressAdd" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="btnAddressAdd_click()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:1.2em"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" id="btnAddressRemove" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="btnAddressRemove_click()" ng-disabled="AddressControls.length==1">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:1.2em"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />

        <fieldset class="row " id="Address" ng-repeat="item in AddressControls"  ng-disabled="$first">

        <div class="col-sm-1" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label >
                prefix
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <span></span>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="prefixSelecteditem" ng-options="prefix.Title for prefix in AddressPrefix">
                    <option value="">--select option--</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="errorBlock">
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" style="height:32px">
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

[*link of source code in codepen*](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxeQvY)

#### Edit

I have some ideas how to to do it when "Addbutton" clicked but I am wondering how its possible to achieve this functionality when there are some active combo boxes and user selects or changes the option of one of them.

Comment: whats the reason for downvoting? whats the problem ?

Comment: down voting is deserved for people that treat invisibly. and have nothing to say for what  they are doing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many approaches to achieve this. here is two of them:

Method 1: Using Angular Filter In HTML

```js
var MainApplication = angular.module('mainApplication', []);

MainApplication.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.AddressPrefix = [{
    id: 1,
    Title: 'AAA',
    priority: 1
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'BBB',
    priority: 2
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'CCC',
    priority: 3
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'DDD',
    priority: 4
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'EEE',
    priority: 5
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'FFF',
    priority: 6
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'GGG',
    priority: 7
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'HHH',
    priority: 8
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'III',
    priority: 2
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'jjj',
    priority: 2
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'kkk',
    priority: 2
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'LLL',
    priority: 10
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'MMM',
    priority: 9
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'ooo',
    priority: 7
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'PPP',
    priority: 12
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'qqq',
    priority: 3
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'RRR',
    priority: 13
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'zzz',
    priority: 14
  }, ];

  $scope.AddressControls = [{
    id: 1
  }];
  $scope.btnAddressAdd_click = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.AddressControls.length + 1
    $scope.AddressControls.push({
      'id': newItemNo
    });
  };
  $scope.btnAddressRemove_click = function() {
    $scope.AddressControls.pop();
  };

  $scope.myFilter = function(index) {
    return function(option, optionIndex, allOptions) {
      var lastSelectedOption = (index > 0) && $scope.AddressControls[index - 1] && $scope.AddressControls[index - 1].prefixSelecteditem;
      if (!lastSelectedOption) return true;
      return option.priority > lastSelectedOption.priority;
    }
  }
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="mainApplication">

<head>
  <title></title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body dir="rtl" ng-controller="mainController">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <button type="button" id="btnAddressAdd" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="btnAddressAdd_click()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:1.2em"></span>
   </button>
      <button type="button" id="btnAddressRemove" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="btnAddressRemove_click()" ng-disabled="AddressControls.length==1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:1.2em"></span>
   </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />

  <fieldset class="row " id="Address" ng-repeat="item in AddressControls track by $index" ng-disabled="$first">

    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <div class="form-group">

        <label>
    prefix
    </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <span></span>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.prefixSelecteditem" ng-options="prefix.Title for prefix in AddressPrefix | filter: myFilter($index)">
     <option value="">--select option--</option>
    </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="errorBlock">
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" style="height:32px">
      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>


</body>

</html>
```

[Method 1 CodePen](http://codepen.io/hosseinMoradi/pen/qNWYvQ?editors=1010)

Method 2: Using Angular Filter In Controller

```js
var MainApplication = angular.module('mainApplication', []);

MainApplication.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.AddressPrefix = [{
    id: 1,
    Title: 'AAA',
    priority: 1
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'BBB',
    priority: 2
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'CCC',
    priority: 3
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'DDD',
    priority: 4
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'EEE',
    priority: 5
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'FFF',
    priority: 6
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'GGG',
    priority: 7
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'HHH',
    priority: 8
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'III',
    priority: 2
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'jjj',
    priority: 2
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'kkk',
    priority: 2
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'LLL',
    priority: 10
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'MMM',
    priority: 9
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'ooo',
    priority: 7
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'PPP',
    priority: 12
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'qqq',
    priority: 3
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'RRR',
    priority: 13
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Title: 'zzz',
    priority: 14
  }, ];

  $scope.AddressControls = [{
    id: 1
  }];
  $scope.btnAddressAdd_click = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.AddressControls.length + 1
    $scope.AddressControls.push({
      'id': newItemNo
    });
  };
  $scope.btnAddressRemove_click = function() {
    $scope.AddressControls.pop();
  };

  $scope.myFilter = function(arr, index) {
    var lastSelectedOption = (index > 0) && $scope.AddressControls[index - 1] && $scope.AddressControls[index - 1].prefixSelecteditem;
    if (!lastSelectedOption) return arr;
    return arr.filter(function (option) {
      return option.priority > lastSelectedOption.priority;
    });
  }
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="mainApplication">

<head>
  <title></title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body dir="rtl" ng-controller="mainController">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <button type="button" id="btnAddressAdd" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="btnAddressAdd_click()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:1.2em"></span>
   </button>
      <button type="button" id="btnAddressRemove" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="btnAddressRemove_click()" ng-disabled="AddressControls.length==1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:1.2em"></span>
   </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />

  <fieldset class="row " id="Address" ng-repeat="item in AddressControls track by $index" ng-disabled="$first">

    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <div class="form-group">

        <label>
    prefix
    </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <span></span>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.prefixSelecteditem" ng-options="prefix.Title for prefix in myFilter(AddressPrefix, $index)">
     <option value="">--select option--</option>
    </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="errorBlock">
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" style="height:32px">
      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>


</body>

</html>
```

[Method 2 CodePen](http://codepen.io/hosseinMoradi/pen/MegGRO)

In first one we use angular filter to filter the options array, and in the second, we simply pass our array to a function in controller and return just the options we needed to show.

I think the first method is the better way, but the second one is simpler and easier to understand!

**Edit:**
The solution for your Edit session is [here](http://codepen.io/hosseinMoradi/pen/ezYdVW?editors=1010)!

Comment: I have an Edit section in my question ,just out of curiosity , If we want to keep the results correct by this way I think we should disable previous combo boxes in previous rows ? am i right ? I am wondering is there a solution to keep things dynamically without disabling controls , I mean that when one of the combo options changed in one of the previous rows only the next combo in next row will be changed not all of them , it would be awesome if other combos could change automatically , but I have no idea is that possible or not ?

Comment: thank you for sharing your knowledge , and thank you for spending  your time  on this question , the solution has a great idea but in some cases it fails if you are interested I can tell you ... but any way I got the idea and I really appreciate it  .....